# jQuery select and wrap textNode

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, textnode

I want to select the text inside the div element and wrap it with a `<b>` tag. The `<b>` tag should only wrap to text inside div and not text inside a child element such as the `<p>` tag in this example.

```
<div>Testing
    <p>Some more text inside p</p>
    <p>asdasdasdasdasde p</p>
    Test
</div>
```

I'm able to select the `<p>` text using the following, but I'm not able to do the same for `div`. I only want the text of `div` and not `p`. For this case it should select and wrap `Testing` and `Test`.

```
var x = $('p')[0].textContent; // this is not working for div.
console.log(x);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nJqKq/5/)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use [`contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/), and filter by node type (3 is for text node):

```
$('div').contents()
        .filter(function(){return this.nodeType === 3})
        .wrap('<b />');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nJqKq/8

See also: [Node Types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType), at MDC

Comment: Thanks guys. Actually, this one is quite verbose compared to the average jQuery line `:)`

Comment: For me it not only wraps "Test" in `b` tag but also creates 4-5 additional `b` tags in between all other tags (ie in empty places - probably empty text nodes), so it's not working well. Testing in Chrome Canary - it looks like it adds unwanted white spaces.

Comment: It does this for every: `data: "↵"` (printed `contents()` to find this) and it adds carriage return/enter automatically.

Comment: Note: `contents` function cannot access cross domain site's iframe

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 7):

Via pure JS and the DOM:

HTML:

```
<div id="test">Testing
    <p>Some more text inside p</p>
    <p>asdasdasdasdasde p</p>
    Test
</div>
```

JS:

```
getTextNodes(document.getElementById("test"));

function getTextNodes(parent)
{
    var textNodes = [];
    var nodes = parent.childNodes;
    for(var i=0;i<nodes.length;i++)
    {
        if(nodes[i].nodeType === 3)
        {   
            textNodes.push(nodes[i]);
            wrapBold(nodes[i], parent);
        }
    }
}

function wrapBold(node, parent)
{
    //check for whitespace text nodes
    if(node.data.match(/[^\t\n\r ]/))
    {
        var bold = document.createElement("strong");
        parent.insertBefore(bold, node);
        bold.appendChild(node);
    }else
    {
        return false;   
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dnjsY/5/

Answer (score 5):

if you dont want to wrap empty nodes use the following:

```
$('div').contents()
        .filter(function(){ 
            return this.nodeType === 3  && this.data.trim().length > 0
         }).wrap('<b />');
```