# I want to hide a character from between links

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I hide the category tag "Featured" by using `remove()` method so it is hidden now I also want to hide the comma from here with jquery but I couldn't. I used `remove()` method for that but it is hiding the next link also. so please help me someone. Thanks.

```
<P class="cat">
<a href="#" >Featured</a>
, 

<a href="#">Others</a>
</P>
```

Comment: Put the comma in a span tag and manipulate.

Comment: How, can you tell me some more details please? @mplungjan

Comment: `<script>$('.cat a:contains("Featured")').css('display','none'); 
$('.cat:contains(",")').wrap('<span></span>');</script>`

Tried it but didn't work... @GaryHayes

Comment: <span id="comma">,</span>  <script>$('#comma").hide();</script>

Comment: I used the above code but it is wrapping the whole `<p>` tag with `<span>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [jQuery select and wrap textNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291703/jquery-select-and-wrap-textnode)

```
$('p').contents()
    .filter(function(){return this.nodeType === 3})
    .wrap('<span />');
```

I eventually came up with this

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/8rLhM/)

```
// select and wrap all commas
$('.cat')
  .contents()
  .filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue)==",";
  })
  .wrap("<span class='comma' />");

// hide all links containing "Featured" as innerHTML
$(".cat").find('a:contains("Featured")').hide();

// select all visible elements
var $coll = $(".cat").children(":visible");
$coll.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.prop("tagName")=="SPAN") { 
      if ($coll.index(this)===0 || 
          $this.nextAll(":visible").prop("tagName")=="SPAN") {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: I have used it and it is working. But one point is that if there comes more than one category names then will the comma appear or not?

Comment: Great, Thank you very much. But I requested you to remove the site links from the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. I used the second one but it is making a little problem. It is hiding the next comma after "featured" as we used `next()` but if the comma becomes before "featured" name then it is not hiding. I update your jsfiddle, check it: http://jsfiddle.net/R8PJx/11/

Comment: My problem is solved but I am just exploring the problem. I used prev() and next() both here. But it is making problem. To understand more you can check this fiddle please: http://jsfiddle.net/R8PJx/17/

Comment: Please see update. I have requested the question to be opened again since it was more complicated than just wrapping

Comment: Yes, It is working awesome. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/R8PJx/18/ . Thanks. I think we should close the problem here.