# How to do in jquery adding new element?

Tags: jquery

I have:

```
<li class="active"><a href="/">Start</a></li>
```

How to do in jquery adding new element:

```
<li class="active"><a href="/"><em><span>Start</span></em></a></li>
```

I need to add `<em><span> </span></em>`

Comment: [jQuery Select and wrap textNode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291703/jquery-select-and-wrap-textnode)

Comment: Give [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) a look as well. Doing DOM manipulation is quick and dirty, but if you're wanting to build a more maintainable code base then switching to a MVVM structure will help by making it so you don't have to rewrite your code everytime you change your markup, and vice versa.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`.wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) to un-obstructively insert new tags within an *existing* DOM element

```
$('.active a').wrapInner('<em><span></span></em>');
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/az8PA/

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$('li.active a').each(function () {
$(this).wrapInner('<em><span></span></em>');
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KRbvG/1/)**

Comment: what if more than one active element?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li.active a').each(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<em><span>' + text + '</span></em>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
<li class="active"><a href="/" id="sample">Start</a></li>

    $("#sample").empty();
    $("#sample").append('<em><span>Start</span>');
```

**now you got following:**

```
<li class="active"><a href="/"><em><span>Start</span></em></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/66SRN/

```
$('li a').wrapInner('<em><span></span></em>');
```

Comment: so all LI A have same content same now