# JavaScript finding dynamic string inside div and wrap it

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<div class="side">
    <a>Link 1</a>
    <a>Link 2</a>
    <input value="1"/>
      / 12
</div>
```

I have the above and I'm trying to figure out how to wrap the `/ 12` with `<span>` the `12` does change.

I've tried

```
var input = angular.element( document.querySelectorAll( '.side input'));
angular.element(input).append('<span>');
```

*desired outcome*

```
<div class="side">
    <a>Link 1</a>
    <a>Link 2</a>
    <span class="page-count">
        <input value="1"/>
          / 12
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Since you are using angularjs why not just make a `<span>` in your html template that holds an angular expression? for example `<span>{{page_count}}</span>` where `page_count` is some `$scope` property that holds your page count. Then you wouldn't have to worry about modifying html

Comment: @PatrickEvans It's from a core vendor and rather not change that in the event the vendor gets updated when running bower

Comment: You need this: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 1):

`wrap()` alone will not work, if you want to wrap a group of elements (the input and the "/12" text node) , as it wraps each one individually.

You need to find the relevant nodes, i.e. the input and text nodes, `detach()` them from the DOM, `append()` them to your new span, then append the span to the original div.

You can include text nodes by using [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) and checking the [`nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5291776/1901857).

### jQuery

With full jQuery, this isn't *too* bad:

```
$('.side').append(function() {

    // create the span, add the detached nodes to it, then append to the container
    $('<span class="page-count"/>').append($(this).contents().filter(function(){

        // filter() contents down to textNodes and the input element, then detach() them all in one jQuery object
        return((this.nodeType === 3 && this.textContent.trim().length > 0)
            || (this.tagName && this.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'INPUT'))

    }).detach()).appendTo(this);

});
```

```js
$('.side').append(function() {

    // create the span, add the detached nodes to it, then append to the container
 $('<span class="page-count"/>').append($(this).contents().filter(function(){

        // filter() contents down to textNodes and the input element, then detach() them all in one jQuery object
       return((this.nodeType === 3 && this.textContent.trim().length > 0)
         || (this.tagName && this.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'INPUT'))

    }).detach()).appendTo(this);

});
```

```css
span.page-count {
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="side">
    <a>Link 1</a>
    <a>Link 2</a>
    <input value="1"/>
      / 12
</div>
```

### Angular

With jqLite, it's not quite as neat. Just replacing `$(this)` with `angular.element(this)` doesn't work, even though most of these jQuery functions are supported in jqLite. The problem comes down to `filter()` being unsupported, which makes it awkward to `detach()` all the necessary elements in one go.

I got around this by changing the statement above into a `forEach()` and detach/appending one at a time:

```
// store the '.side' container
var sideElem = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.side'));
// create the new span
var pageCount = angular.element('<span class="page-count"/>');

// loop through contents of '.side'
angular.forEach(sideElem.contents(), function(val) {
    // if node matches, detach() it from '.side' and append() to the span
    if((val.nodeType === 3 && val.textContent.trim().length > 0)
        || (val.tagName && val.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'INPUT')) {
    pageCount.append(angular.element(val).detach());
  }
});

// add the span to the '.side' container
sideElem.append(pageCount);
```

```js
// store the '.side' container
var sideElem = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.side'));
// create the new span
var pageCount = angular.element('<span class="page-count"/>');
    
// loop through contents of '.side'
angular.forEach(sideElem.contents(), function(val) {
    // if node matches, detach() it from '.side' and append() to the span
    if((val.nodeType === 3 && val.textContent.trim().length > 0)
        || (val.tagName && val.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'INPUT')) {
        pageCount.append(angular.element(val).detach());
    }
});
    
// add the span to the '.side' container
sideElem.append(pageCount);
```

```css
span.page-count {
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="side">
    <a>Link 1</a>
    <a>Link 2</a>
    <input value="1"/>
      / 12
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling) to achieve that.

It would look something like this:

```
var input = angular.element( document.querySelectorAll( '.side input'));
var textNode = input.nextSibling();
angular.element(textNode).append('<span>');
```

I am not entirely sure though, but I think something close to it should do the job.

Answer (score -1):

```
var lastText = addDiv[0].childNodes;
var lastTextIndex = addDiv[0].childNodes.length;
angular.element( lastText[lastTextIndex-1]).wrap('<span class="page-count">')
```