# Convert text node into HTML element using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div>
    aaaa
    <span>bbbb</span>
    cccc
    <span>dddd</span>
    eeee
</div>
```

I use JQuery to match the `[aaaa, cccc, eeee]` text nodes by following the [answers in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery):

```
$('div').contents().filter(function()
{
    return this.nodeType === 3;
});
```

Now, I want to replace every text node with an HTML element - say a `<div>` containing the text node. This is my desired result:

```
<div>
    <div>aaaa</div>
    <span>bbbb</span>
    <div>cccc</div>
    <span>dddd</span>
    <div>eeee</div>
</div>
```

I've tried to use various closures passed to `.each`. E.g.:

```
$('div').contents().filter(function()
{
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).each(function()
{
    this.html("<div>" + this.text() + "</div>");
});
```

But it seems that the text nodes do not provide any `.html` method. **How can I replace a text node with an arbitrary HTML element using JQuery?**

Comment: Why not fix this in the markup instead of band-aid'ing it after the fact with javascript?  And maybe give the `replaceWith` method a lookie loo.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291703/jquery-select-and-wrap-textnode

Comment: `$(this).html()` use this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery select and wrap textNode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291703/jquery-select-and-wrap-textnode)

Comment: @Taplar: I have no control over the markup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` refers to a plain DOM node element that doesn't implement neither an `html()` nor a `text()` method. Using `$(this)`, you can make the element into a jQuery collection in order to be able to access the jQuery methods. Then you can use `replaceWith()` to replace the plain text nodes with the `<div>`s.

```js
$('div').contents().filter(function()
{
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).each(function()
{
    $(this).replaceWith("<div>" + $(this).text() + "</div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    aaaa
    <span>bbbb</span>
    cccc
    <span>dddd</span>
    eeee
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `wrap` from jquery to wrap the content with `div`

> ## .wrap()
>
> Description: Wrap an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched elements.
>
> REF: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

```js
$('div').contents().filter(function()
{
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).each(function()
{
    $(this).wrap('<div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    aaaa
    <span>bbbb</span>
    cccc
    <span>dddd</span>
    eeee
</div>
```